# How could i combine multiple programs together in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a few different programs I want to combine into one big program, but I'm not sure how to do that. My programs are:

```
import random
Level = int(input('What level is the chest?'))
GP = (random.randint(0, 10))
SP = (random.randint(10, 50))
CP = (random.randint(0, 100))

print ((GP * Level),'GP')
print ((SP * Level),'SP')
print ((CP * Level),'CP')
```

and

```
Number = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll?'))
Sides =  int(input('How many sides?'))
import random
for Number in range(Number):
  print (random.randint(1, Sides))
```

and

```
import random
classes = ["Dwarf","Elf","Halfling","Human","Dragonborn","Gnome","Half-
Elf","Half-Orc","Tiefling"]
r = random.randint(1, 9)
print("Your class is {}".format(classes[r - 1]))
```

I would also like to know how to add new programs to this. (Yes this is D&D)

Comment: just paste them into one file in the order you need them to run. Remove duplicate imports. Whats the issue?

Comment: How do you want the big program to behave?  Do you want it to do the functions exactly in the order shown -- chest, then dice, then class?  If so, then you can just paste the code together into one big file and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to run any of these blocks during the course of play, you  could use [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and a [while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) loop to choose which block to run. Maybe something like this:

```
import random

def get_level():
    Level = int(input('What level is the chest?'))
    GP = (random.randint(0, 10))
    SP = (random.randint(10, 50))
    CP = (random.randint(0, 100))
    print ((GP * Level),'GP')
    print ((SP * Level),'SP')
    print ((CP * Level),'CP')

def get_roll():
    Number = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll?'))
    Sides =  int(input('How many sides?'))
    for Number in range(Number):
        print (random.randint(1, Sides))

def get_class():
    classes = ["Dwarf","Elf","Halfling","Human","Dragonborn","Gnome",
               "Half-Elf","Half-Orc","Tiefling"]
    r = random.randint(1, 9)
    print("Your class is {}".format(classes[r - 1]))

choice = None
while choice != 'quit':
    choice = input('What next? [level, roll, class, quit] ').lower()
    if choice == 'level':
        get_level()
    elif choice == 'roll':
        get_roll()
    elif choice == 'class':
        get_class()
    elif choice == 'quit':
        pass
    else:
        print('Sorry, please try again.')
```